# In a resume, how to show "years of experience" instead of stars / progress bar, yet being eye-catching?

Tags: resume

I'm building my resume, and I would like to put years of experience in a section called "Skills", for example, React, PHP, JavaScript, etc.

[image]

I'm not sure about using Stars / Dots / Progress bars (since I would never put 5/5 on something as I know there's always something I didn't know) and I would prefer to use "Up to 2 years", "2-5 years", "5+ years".

I'm wondering what would be a good way to show this, since "Up to 2 years" is still something good.

Maybe using 1 Star/icon for "Up to two years", same icon but different color for "2-5 years" and the same icon with a fire or something for "5+" years? For example, like Duolingo does

[image]

Comment: Please do not use graphs, bars, or stars in your resume to show experience. Personal opinion, but it looks very juvenile. At best it shows that you know a program and at worst it shows what you don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Experience should be written out.

While graphs and bars may be more *visually* interesting, they can be equally problematic for a resumé/CV.

Many Human Resource departments use OCR (Optical Character Recognition), to digitally "read" resumes and create a database. Graphs, charts, etc don't get read.

In addition, the **goal** of any resumé/cv is to be clear in order to get a call back. "2 years experience with Javascript, PHP, and ASP" is *much* more clear than some nebulous graph or chart.

---

For example, in the question's sample image... There is **no way** to tell what the graphs mean. Is the black 1 year? 1 week? 1 month? 20 years? 1,000 years? Or does the black indicate *all possible Earthly knowledge* in that area? So... what's the green *actually* equate to?

At *best* it may be gleaned from the graph that the person is a bit better at front end and Wordpress development, than they are at backend.

But.. if they honestly suck with Front End/Wordpress, that just means they are pretty horrible with Back End dev. But, what if the person is exceptional with Front End/Wordpress? That may mean they are pretty good with Back End just perhaps not as confident.

So, the graph either means you suck... or you're fantastic... there's no way to know which one *may* be true. Ambiguity is often a sure-fire way to get "passed over" by potential employers.

---

In addition, using an application/language for any period of time *in no way* reflects *actual* proficiency in that application/language. I've had Word on my systems for 30+ years... but I'd still consider myself a "novice" in terms of proficiency within Word because *how* I use it doesn't require any more than novice knowledge. But hey, I wouldn't be lying if I made a graph to show 30 years of use....

People that **read** resumés/CVs and do the hiring are *not* looking at such graphs as a basis for ranking prospective candidates. They **read the text** of the resumé/CV. If experience and knowledge in specific areas/languages is imperative to you're being hired, you need to clearly define what your skills are in *text*.

##### Do yourself a favor and skip the graphs... and create well formatted *text* describing your proficiencies.

I know there's a "trend" to have these graphs on a resumé/CV.. but in all honesty they do more harm than good because they don't *actually* convey any real, hard, facts. They are nothing more than superfluous "visual noise" without any benefit.

---

<sub>(Possible added benefit: Due to the marked trend of including such graphs, *not* having one will do more to make you stand out as an individual rather than a follower.)</sub>

Comment: Do you mean something like this?  https://pasteboard.co/5O0e4076kjnl.png

Comment: @JorgeeFG Yes. That is **much** more informative and clear than any random graph. If you include such text, and **also** want to include a graph that would probably be okay as well. The imperative part is to have the text so your qualifications are clear and readable.

Comment: Thank you for your input

Comment: @JorgeeFG  First, I wouldn't post personal information like that. Hopefully you can break the link in some what... but Yes, That's a much more impressive resume than something with a random graph. (I, personally, would *never* have my photo on a resume - it merely makes discrimination by employers easier. If they want to know what I look like, they need to schedule an interview. - but that's your call.)

Comment: Glad you were still able to delete that comment `:)`